# Where is Html.Serialize in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I know the MVC3 futures dll Microsoft.Web.MVC has Html.Serialize. But if I'm building an app using mvc4 do I still need to install mvc3 futures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the NuGet package for `Mvc3Futures` and this will resolve the problem.  I don't think that there is a pure Mvc4 version of `Futures` just yet.

Answer (score 12):

Futures for MVC4 is available as of 11/30/12

https://nuget.org/packages/Mvc4Futures/4.0.20710.0